# Firebase Auth Not Persisting on SubDomain--Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase v3.2.1

When I authenticate on e.g. 'example.com', the session will persist if I go to a different page e.g. 'example.com/page3', but will not persist if I got to a page e.g. 'max.example.com'.

How do I keep the session persist when I go on the subdomain page?

Comment: Firebase auth sessions currently persist in single host origin only. You will need to login the same user in the other subdomain. BTW, I recommend you upgrade to the latest version 3.4.

Comment: @bojeil This question and your comment saved me a lot of time. Thanks!